# Elementary inequality proof $2|tx|\leq |x^2|+|t^2|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove the following inequality for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ und $t\in \mathbb{C}$:
$$2|tx|\leq |t^2|+|x^2|$$

I have for $t=a+bi$:
$$|t^2|=|a^2-b^2+aib|=\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}$$
and 
$$2|tx|=2\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
reaching
$$2\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\leq\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^2}+x^2 $$

How do I continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lvert x\rvert^2+\lvert t\rvert^2-2\lvert xt\rvert=\lvert x\rvert^2+\lvert t\rvert^2-2\lvert x\rvert\lvert t\rvert=\bigl(\lvert x\rvert-\lvert t\rvert\bigr)^2\geqslant0.$$

Comment: I want $|t^2|$ not norm squared. The norm isn't muktiolivative for complex numbers right?

Comment: Yes, it is: $(\forall z,w\in\mathbb{C}):\lvert zw\rvert=\lvert z\rvert\lvert w\rvert$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $$0\le |x|^2+|t|^2-2|tx|$$ it is $$0\le (|x|-|t|)^2$$

Comment: Why is that correct